# Grains vs Cereals

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

How would you *peas, green peas, split peas, beans* and *green beans* under the same name? How about *wheat, oat* and *rice*?

Based on dictionaries definitions, both ***grains*** and ***cereal*** work for both groups, but in my language we should put them in different group names.

Answer (score 3):

Peas and beans are **pulses** (edible seeds that grow in pods). Wheat. oats, and rice are **grains** The main difference between cereals and pulses is that the cereals are the grasses which belong to the monocot family Poaceae. They are gathered for their starch-rich grains.

Comment: You are very likely to hear 'pulses' used in that sense where I live (UK).

Comment: Interesting--very unlikely in the US, as far as I'm aware!

Comment: If you are vegetarian and like to eat organic food, grains and pulses are things you think and talk about. Maybe people who eat KFC not so much.

Comment: In the US, I've heard "legumes" far more often than "pulses" in conversational discussions about food.